# Why is it that if it is me and not my mom giving dry cat food, she will wait until I disappear from her sight?

Tags: cats, behavior, feeding

My cat has this peculiar behavior.

If it is boiled fish then my cat goes mad, and will accept food from any family member and eat it immediately. But if it is anybody other than family member, she will not even accept fish.

If it is my mom and food is dry cat food then she will sit guarding the food and meow at my mom to caress her. My mom will have to sit beside her and start caressing her. Then she starts purring and eating.

If it is me then my cat will sit guarding the food and look at me saying as if, "Now go away". I have to hide myself. She will carefully look if I am out of her sight. Then she will start eating.

Last scenario, she has eaten some dry food and no more hungry, but food is there in food bowl, she brings one food by her foot down to floor, play football for sometime, then eat it. And she will continue it.

Now the thing which puzzles me the most is why my cat waits for me to get out of sight before she starts eating?